# Group with “full control” not allowed to add users in Owner group with customer Group

Tags: security, sharepoint-2010

I have updated the “owners group” permission level to not allow Owners to add sub sites. Then I added an administrators group that has the out of the box “full control”. My issue is that the “administrators group” and the “owners group” are going to be able to manage the members group and “owners group”. But the “owners group” is not going to be able to manage users in the “administrators group”. I can only see that a group can have one “Group Owner”.

This there a way to make a work around, so “administrators group” and “owners group” can manage the same groups?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a custom group and use that one as the 'group owner'